# A Java reflection wrapper code generator?

Tags: java, reflection

I'd like to work with a class that is only available in my runtime environment, and I don't have any .java or .class files of it. The only way to use it AFAIK is through reflection.

What I already did, is to write a small program to get the `Class` instance of my target class, iterate through its public methods/fields and get their signature (similar as in [this program](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Reflection/DumpaclassusingReflection.htm)). This will give me a skeleton of a .java source file. Then I manually filled the bodies of those methods so that they call the real methods using reflection. The so-made Java file is compiled by javac, together with my user code. This way I could use the target class without filling my code with Method/Field getters.

Here are my questions:

- Is there a specific term for what I'm trying to do? ("Java reflection wrapper code generator" maybe?)
- Is there a tool that automates the task I did manually above?
- If not, what are the challenges in building such a tool?

Comment: "I don't have any .class files of it". That sounds unlikely. Are you building the class in memory, or how come you don't have a class file?

Comment: I would say you are trying to write a bridging object which uses reflection to build it.

Comment: Sounds to me like you are buiilding a [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html)

Comment: @Kayaman I'm trying to use undocumented APIs in the runtime environment, and currently the only "hint" is the API class name.

Comment: I have a tool which provides an AddIn for Spreadsheets and does this under the hood - Obba http://obba.info - a challange is polymorphism / method overriding, because AFAIK you have to select the appropriate method yourself.   - For the naming: I am confused by the word "code generator".

Comment: @ChristianFries I added some more details to the question, hoping to explain why I need a tool that generates code. About overriding: doesn't the JVM take care of the overrides when I `invoke` the public method?

Comment: Is your question about pattern name, or its implementation?

Comment: It sound like the public interfaces of both (source and generated class) are the same and the generated one only delegates to the source (without any interception code)? So why don't you use the original class? The API may be undocumented, but most IDEs can show you the public interface (API).

Answer (score 2):

What you try to do is a Proxy Class. Lot of framework use it to inject some automation, transactions etc... Java EE, Spring, for example.

There are 2 ways:
The simple one with java.lang.reflect.Proxy, but it has a constraints: your class must implements an interface, and only method in Interface can be called.

The more complex one rely on bytecode generation, you can use the Mockito framework that generate all what you need: it is intended for tests, but can be also used to generate any kind of class wich override an existing one.

I may complete my answer with example if you need it.